# Malformed JSON Fixing

Tags: python, java, json

I've a JSON file which is malformed, and I want to solve the issues on that JSON file via code block. Which language helps me better to do that (probably python), what is the steps which I have to do for fixing that malformed file. As far as I've checked the internet, regular expression library is important for this solution, what are the things I need to check for fixing it.

Right now I'm trying, reading the JSON file via Python, then I'll open the file with JSON editor to compile the file. From that return values, I'll try to fix what else I've to do for solving that error.
My second approach for this issue is, I'll try to find the model of the malformed JSON file and import on my python code, code will fits my file to JSON file on my format. For this second solution, I feel this will fixes the issues better than first approach but only fits for this JSON file.

Is there another approach for this issue?

Thanks for the all of the helps.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details on the actual problem. However, if the JSON is malformed you'll very likely not be able to automatically fix it because it could be anything. Parsing error messages and automatically handling them is not easy, especially since the error might not be the actual source of the problem. Better try to tackle the source of the malformed file, i.e. fix the marshalling right at the source.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Which I understand your opinion, for every malformed JSON, we have to create a new solution, that bring us the my second solution I presume.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to write a fault tolerant parser for parsing the malformed JSON, then print the AST to a valid JSON. Or you could just use some existing libraries and tools like https://github.com/josdejong/jsonrepair.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is also very helpful for seeing different situations. If I can translate it to Python or Java, it'll be great. Thanks for the answering!